# LOAD INFILE syntax error

Tags: mysql, syntax

I've been trying this in different ways, can anyone spot the syntax error?

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/projects.csv' INTO TABLE 'projects' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (test, test2, test3, test4, test5, test6, test7, test8, test9, test10, test11, test12, test13, test14, test15, test16, test17, test18, test19, test20, test21, test22, test23);
```

I've replaced the names of the columns with the word test, theyre basically project_name, project_author and so on.

Comment: Mysql tells you exactly where that syntax error is.

Comment: Well it says "You have an error in your SQL syntax, check the manual for your version for the right syntax at : LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/projects.csv' INTO TABLE 'projects' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (order_no, product_'               I admit that shortens it a bit but I still don't see the error, do you?

Comment: How do you run this query?

Comment: via my command  prompt on a private server, I go in mysql and then just run it.

Comment: What if you run this: (copy this exact text) `LOAD DATA INFILE;` ?

Comment: same error except now it says "near ' ' "

Comment: Well, is it exactly the same or differs? Looks like you have some invisible characters copied with your original query. That's why I asked you to run another query that provides the *different* error.

Comment: I meant it still says it is a syntax error only now the location is an empty quote '' (I put a space between the ' and ' to show it wasn't a double quote...sorry about that). [just wanted to say thanks for trying]

Comment: "only now the location is an empty quote" --- that's right, because my query is fine apart of that it's not complete. And your begins with some weird invisible characters - that's why you see the whole query in the error message. My advice: re-type manually from scratch as much of your query as possible and run it again.

Comment: tried it, seems like you were partly right, now I get a smaller error area "'projects' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (order_no, product_n"

Comment: Not sure why "partly" then :-) The current mistake is that an identifier is in a single quotes: it must be without quotes at all or in back ticks `

Comment: You're right, you were 100% right and I think you're a God, congratz :D. table name had to be in back ticks, did not realize that. Thank you so much, if you put it as an answer I'd check it + it might help other uncult noobs like me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per discussion in the comments there are 2 issues with you query:

1. There is some invisible character that brings a mess
2. Identifiers (table names, column names, etc) must be either without any quotes around or within back ticks

As of item #1, how I detected it: mysql parser starts with the place in your query that it *cannot parse*. And as soon as your error message contains the complete query but the beginning of your query looks valid - the only explanation is that there is something else that we cannot see but presents in a query.

So the more generic advice on how to react on mysql syntax errors:

Just check the place the parser error points to, including few characters before and after. If you cannot see anything suspicious and if the syntax is correct as per documentation - try to re-type it manually once again, especially if you copied it from somewhere.